# Using useState along with global decorators throws error Storybook preview hooks can only be called inside decorators and story functions

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am using storybook in a monorepo. In my root folder in `preview.js` I have this:

```
export const decorators = [
  (Story) => {
    const theme = createTheme("violet", "gray");
    const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
      *{padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
      ul{ list-style: none}
    `;
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Story />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  },
];
```

When I use decorators along with `useState` in my components, I get,
`Storybook preview hooks can only be called inside decorators and story functions.`

The story:

```
export const Default = () => {
    let items = [
      { id: "1", name: "one" },
     ...
    ];
   
    const [inpItems, setItems] = useState(items);
   
    return (
      <ComboBox
        items={inpItems}
        onInputValueChange={({ inputValue }) => {
          setItems(allItems.filter((item) => item.name.includes(inputValue)));
        }}
        itemToString={(item) => item?.name}
       
      />
    );
  };
```

When I comment out the decorator, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This errors because decorators are functions, not components. Even though you have JSX, it's being called as `myDecorator()` rather than `<MyDecorator />`; completely bypassing React.

You have to create a separate component to hold that `useState` hook, and then you could render the component in the decorator function.

From my experience, this *may* cause issues as sometimes, decorator functions are called 4 or more times per render.

Comment: This was super helpful.   Simply creating a wrapper component and adding it to the `render` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Storybook 7+ update:
This seem to be working with importing the hooks from `@storybook/preview-api`.

Meaning no need for wrapping with another component anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was related to usage of `withThemeByClassName` hook from [@storybook/addon-themes](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-themes) in Storybook 7.

[image: Fix]

Specifically in it's order in the `decorators`. After I've moved it from the first position the `Storybook preview hooks can only be called inside decorators and story functions.` on e.g. `useState` hooks was gone.

Comment: I put it in third place. It still fails.